# EWS - How to know contact fields extended property id?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, extended-properties

I have to add values to some outlook contact fields using EWS. I've managed to do that with the 'User Field 1' using
[this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg274394.aspx)
. The problem is that i need to insert values in other fields (for instance 'Account' in 'Miscellaneous Fields') and I need to know the id of these properties.
Here is the code i'm using to create the property, i need to set the second parameter:

```
Guid myGuid = new Guid("{00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");
ExtendedPropertyDefinition myDef = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(myGuid, 0x804F, MapiPropertyType.String);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, the `PropertyId` values are on the [same MSDN article you referenced](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg274394.aspx#PropertyIdValues).

`Account` is `PropertyId` **0x3A00**.

[MFCMAPI](http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/) is also your friend when looking for Property Names or Ids.